# Infinite loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to increase the number of sets until `workout` is at least as long as `min_workout but not longer than`max_workout`. I am testing with values`min30`,`max40`,`run3`, and`walk2`. It should stop at 5 repeats and total of 33 minutes.

```
warm_cool = 8

puts "What is the least amount of time you want to work out?"
min_workout = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "What is the longest time you want to work out?"
max_workout = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "How many minutes per set do you want to run?" 
run = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "How many minutes do you want to walk each set?"
walk = gets.chomp.to_i 

i = 0  
workout = (run+walk)*i + warm_cool

until workout >=min_workout && workout <=max_workout do
workout = (run+walk)*i+=1 + warm_cool

puts "You need to perform  #{i} repeats and your workout time will be #
{workout} minutes, including a 4 minute warmup and cooldown "

end
```

I can't figure out why I am getting an infinite loop here.

Comment: Put a print in the loop and see what the values are vs what you expect them to be. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Instead of using a loop, why not do the math and divide to determine how many intervals you can fit in?

Comment: @tadman - the lesson is on loops, so I need to use one

Comment: Beware of lessons that enforce using `while` and/or `until` loops in Ruby. They are plain evil.

Comment: I'm with mudasowba here. Ruby has a variety of tools for avoiding this, just like how `for` is hardly ever used yet it's the backbone of code in other languages. If you want to learn Ruby there's probably better ways to do it, but if you need to do this to pass a course that's understandable, it's just a different objective.

Comment: What you are actually trying to achieve with `workout = (run+walk)*i+=1 + warm_cool`?!

Comment: @mudasobwa - Let's say I have a min workout of 30 minutes, and a max workout of 40 minutes, and I want to do a run/walk combo of 3 min/2 min. So I want to start with 1 repeat (13 minutes total - 8 min warmup/cool down, 3 min run, 2 min walk) which would fail the >=30 <=40 test, so it would try 2 repeats (18 minutes total) which would fail again, and so on until it reaches the number of repeats that will put the total between 30 and 40 minutes

Comment: @mudasobwa It depends on the goal of the course. If it's about learning _programming_ in general and not Ruby per se then `for`, `while` et al are important concepts and will be useful later on in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few little slips here that have had some pretty dramatic consequences. First of all is using `+=` in the middle of a statement. That's generally bad form and it's caused absolute chaos here.

The reason for this is your code is evaluated as this:

```
workout = (run + walk) * i += (1 + warm_cool)
```

Since `warm_cool` is 8 then it increments by 9 each time and you can easily skip past the end of your range. This is why it's generally best to limit how many times you try things to a reasonable count. Wrapping it in a simple method also helps contain things and makes managing flow easier:

```
def intervals_required(run, walk, warm_cool, range)
  10.times do |i|
    workout = (run + walk) * i + warm_cool

    return i if range.include?(workout)
  end

  # Couldn't find a matching interval
  nil
end
```

Where you call it like this:

```
if (intervals = intervals_required(run, walk, (min_workout..max_workout))
  puts "..."
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking that your first iteration is yielding the expression

```
(3 + 2) * 0 + 1 + 8
```

which would evaluate correctly, but you need to understand the way `+=` works under the hood.

Underneath the syntax conveniences of `+=` given to you by Ruby, you're actually doing a few things at once. `+=` is an assignment method, and everything to the right of it is an argument to the method and wrapped in implicit parentheses, as in `i += (1 + 8)`. It's actually two method calls in one, adding the receiver to the argument before assignment, like so

```
i = i + (1 + 8)
```

Underneath all the syntactic sugar it really looks like this with dot notation and parentheses

```
i.=(i.+(1 + 8))
```

So instead of

```
(3 + 2) * 1 + 8
5 * 1 + 8 
5 + 8
13
```

on the first pass you're actually getting

```
(3 + 2) * (i = 0 + (1 + 8))
(3 + 2) * 9
5 * 9
45
```

and skipping your upper condition of `40`, so it just keeps going. `i` is now set to `9`, and `i` increases by 9 on each pass, so your next result is `90`, then `135`, and so on.

Try wrapping the assignment in parentheses, like this

```
(run + walk) * (i += 1) + 8
```

Also consider adding a guard clause inside your loop to prevent infinite repetition, something like `break if workout > max_workout`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you problem is that you have reached an invalid state with your `until` loop and it just keeps going out of bounds.  Your logic makes sense for a `while` type scenario because you want it to stop whenever both of those are `true`.  However with an `until` it will break from the loop when your condition equals true.

So if `workout` is more than the `max_workout` it will keep incrementing since it will never satisfy the conditional and the `until` will keep going.